# Why does my code crash when calling free?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the C standard library in C++ just to see if I remember it well.. Turns out I don't..
 However, I allocated some strings on the heap and when I try to delete them, I get access violation and a crash..

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void substr(char* str, std::size_t offset, std::size_t pos, char* buffer)
{
    for (unsigned i = offset, j = 0; i < pos; ++i, ++j)
        buffer[j] = str[i];
}

void substr(char* str, std::size_t pos, char* buffer)
{
    substr(str, pos, strlen(str), buffer);
}

int countstr(char* StringToSplit, char* Delimiter)
{
    int count = 0;

    char* ptr = strstr(StringToSplit, Delimiter);
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        ++count;
        ptr = strstr(ptr + 1, Delimiter);
    }
    return count;
}

void SplitString(char* StringToSplit, char* Delimiter, char** Result)
{
    int i = 0;
    char* ptr = strtok(StringToSplit, Delimiter);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        Result[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1);
        strcpy(Result[i], ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, Delimiter);
        ++i;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char str[] = "Hello there nooby noob";
    int len = countstr(str, " ");

    char** strs = (char**)malloc(len * sizeof(char*));

    SplitString(str, " ", strs);

    for (int i = 0; i < len + 1; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s, ", strs[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len + 1; ++i)
    {
        free(strs[i]);
    }

    free(strs);
}
```

it prints:

```
"Hello, there, nooby, noob".
```

which is correct. The only problem I have is freeing my allocations. It for some reason won't let me.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `I'm trying to write some C in C++` What does this mean? You mean you're deliberately writing C then compiling it as C++, making it entirely non-idiomatic? Why?

Comment: new and delete are not part of C. Use malloc and free if you're trying to write C

Comment: strs != NULL is always true, your cycle lasts forever

Comment: There. I used `free` and `malloc`.

Comment: I think your code is invalid. It should fail on printf, not on delete.

Comment: Still the same thing. I updated the OP.

Comment: strs[len + 1] points to unallocated area

Comment: Ahh that fixed it. I had to `malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char*))`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames `delete` won't set a pointer to NULL. If you want it to be NULL, set it to NULL, otherwise like a previous comment said, it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop

```
 while(strs != NULL)
    delete[] strs[j++];
```

will not work. `delete` will not affect the value of strs (you don't want that, actually), so you're deleting the same string over and over again.

Comment: I think delete[] is OK, but this is actually a never ending loop, but finally delete[] works on pointer from outside array causing segfault

Comment: @marcin_j: That's right. And it will crash once j gets larger than the array.